# Pass variables to another class?

Tags: xna-4.0

How do i pass a variable to another class?
These two classes are not my main.
The variable I want to use in class1 is test which is int 5 from class2.

Answer (score 0):

You Can make them public(or, eben better, use get set) and then you habe access to them.
    public int Name;